# Cocoapods could not find comatible versions for pod "Capacitor"

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have update the Xcode to latest version 12.5 and after that I was getting below error for capacitor

> switch must be exhaustive xcode

Then to resolve this error I ran the below command and it got resolved

```
npm install @capacitor/ios@latest
```

Then I was trying to sync the ios project it has started to give the following error now

> Cocoapods could not find compatible versions for pod "Capacitor": In
> Podfile: capacitor (from '.../../node_modules/capacitor/ios) Specs
> satisfying the 'Capacitor (from '.../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios')'
> dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment
> target

to solve this error I have tried below commands on root level and ios/App folder level also

```
pod install --repo-update
```

But this doesn't seems to resolve the error.

The app is build using ionic framework

Comment: It already said `required a higher minimum deployment target`, you probably need to increase your deployment target version

Comment: @Tj3n Can you please tell where should I do that ? OR what are the steps to do that ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-minimum-version-configuration/202779)?

Comment: @Tj3n Not yet.. Checking

Comment: @Tj3n I have updated capacitor from 1.3.0 to 3.0.2 and macOS updated to Big Sur 11.4 and Xcode to 12.5. Is that causing an issue ?

Comment: @Tj3n As per link we cannot set min ios version for capacitor 3, this needs to be changes in podfile directly. As of now my podfile has platform:ios,'11.0'. So, shouldi change this to 11.4 ?

Comment: Per [this doc](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#set-ios-deployment-target-to-120). Min iOs version should be 12 instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234392/discussion-between-xamdev-and-tj3n).

Comment: @Tj3n yes updated the same in pod file, but still getting the same error ? Any reason

Comment: You need to open the `xcodeproj` file in XCode and bump the iOS version in `Deployment Info` too I think. I'm not using ionic so just providing iOS information. Maybe try `npm install` again too.

Comment: yeah tried that... But nothing is working as of now